# Divide and alot values in a table using python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, grouping

I have the following table (x):

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 23 |
| B1 | 44 |
| Q2 | 66 |
| B5 | 77 |
| L3 | 87 |
| S1 | 90 |
| Q6 | 34 |
| W3 | 123 |
| H9 | 51 |
| K5 | 80 |
| R4 | 19 |
| N8 | 43 |

I would like to split the table into 4 groups (1,2,3,4) in the same order as another column group. The output should look like the following:

| Column1 | Column2 | Groups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 23 | 1 |
| B1 | 44 | 1 |
| Q2 | 66 | 1 |
| B5 | 77 | 2 |
| L3 | 87 | 2 |
| S1 | 90 | 2 |
| Q6 | 34 | 3 |
| W3 | 123 | 3 |
| H9 | 51 | 3 |
| K5 | 80 | 4 |
| R4 | 19 | 4 |
| N8 | 43 | 4 |

What I tried so far?

```
n2 = 4 # number of groups
idx = set(x.index // (round(len(x)/n2)))
grp = [i for i in range(1, n2+1)]
x['Groups'] = (x.index // (round(len(x)/n2))).map(dict(zip(idx, grp)))
```

But that does not work. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

#### `np.arange`

```
df.assign(Groups=np.arange(len(df)) // (len(df) // 4) + 1)

   Column1  Column2  Groups
0       A1       23       1
1       B1       44       1
2       Q2       66       1
3       B5       77       2
4       L3       87       2
5       S1       90       2
6       Q6       34       3
7       W3      123       3
8       H9       51       3
9       K5       80       4
10      R4       19       4
11      N8       43       4
```

Comment: If I try ```df.assign(Groups=np.arange(len(df)) // (len(df) // 4) + 1)``` I get ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero. Is it possible to solve this without suppressing the warnings. Thanks!